# How to communicate between app for login with flutter app

Tags: flutter, authentication, token, deep-linking

I have app (create by flutter) I want to provide this app for login
example flow

1. another app (press login button) will open my app
2. my app show confirm button for login with another app
3. my app return some token to another app (1) and close my app and another app get some token to use ...

Question how to use tools for implement login flow in my app.

Comment: not clear. are you talking about session?

Comment: I want to provide some channel in my app for another app can access for get token from my app. It be like app login with google or facebook.

Comment: why do you use firebase. saving the token there and the other app can get it

Comment: another app cannot access firebase. I think I will  use deep link for communicate between apps